# Nexus Repository Manager

Tags: nexus

We want to install Nexus in an environment where >100 developers use this.

1. What is the max load that Nexus could handle. We might have >50 simultanesous requests for artifacts (a fresh local repo is used on every build)
2. I want to have multiple instances share the repo storage (I have tried and it does not work but wondering if anyone has tried to do this). We want to have one instance of Nexus in Read mode that is in sync with other one in Read/Write mode. Any possibilities?)

Please share your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We have many huge customers running Nexus without load problems, including shops on the order of 10's of thousands of users. That's in addition to the large and public instances at:

http://repository.apache.org

http://nexus.codehaus.org

http://maven.atlassian.com

https://repository.jboss.org/nexus

http://oss.sonatype.org

and many others.

Two Nexus instances can't effectively share the entire storage folder because Lucene is used for many things and those files aren't shareable. It might be possible to share just the repo folder, but the indexes and caches will be out of data on the standby.

Redundancy is something we're working on in commercial Nexus versions.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks a lot for the reply. Multiple instances sharing the same Nexus_home is desired not just for load problems. In our case, we wanted to have different domains to use the same files and not different copies. For example, we wanted the very same Foo.jar in dev domain and  in qa as well. The storage was on network shares in dev & qa, where dev can both write and read; qa is read only.

Comment: This is something we are actively working on for a future release of Nexus Pro.